# Priority Queue Multimap Class with Multiple items of the same key value in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, queue

I am writing a c++ priority queue multi map class that is able to handle multiple items of the same key value.  I have a push method that will create the items in the multimap, and a pop method that will return the item with the highest key value.  I want to be able to add multiple items with the same key value.  If two items have the same key value only one should be popped, and the other should remain in the queue.

Here is my code for the pop method.

```
    string PQ::pop()
   {
int maxKey = 0;
string maxValue;

if(pq.size() > 0)
{
    for(std::multimap<int, string>::iterator iter = pq.begin(); iter != pq.end(); iter++)
    {
        if(iter->first >= maxKey)
        {
            maxKey = iter->first;
            maxValue = iter->second;

        }
    }
}
else
{
    maxValue = "The queue is empty";
}
pq.erase(maxKey);
return maxValue;
    }
```

When I run this code in my main method:

```
    pq.push(1, "one");
    pq.push(3, "three");
    pq.push(3, "three2");
    pq.push(50, "fifty2");
    pq.push(50, "fifty");

    cout << pq.pop() << endl;
    cout << pq.pop() << endl;
    cout << pq.pop() << endl;
    cout << pq.pop() << endl;
    cout << pq.pop() << endl;
```

This is what is printed out:

fifty2
three
one

When it should be:

fifty2
fifty
three
three2
one.

Answer (score 0):

In short: `pq.erase(maxKey)` removes **all** elements with a key equal to `maxKey` - not just one element.

First `pop()` returns only `fifty2` but removes both `fifty2` and `fifty`, second `pop()` returns only `three` but removes both `three` and `three2`, third `pop()` returns and removes `one` and fourth and fifth `pop()`s just return empty string.